# Neural network in keras not converging

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras

I'm building a simple Neural network in Keras, like the following:

```
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=x_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='RMSprop')
# Fit the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=700, verbose=2)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

The shape of the used data is:

```
x_train = (49972, 601) 
y_train = (49972, 1)
```

My problem is that the network is not converging, the accuracy is fixed on 0.0168, like below:

```
Epoch 1/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.2222 - acc: 0.0174
Epoch 2/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1757 - acc: 0.0187
Epoch 3/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1731 - acc: 0.0212
Epoch 4/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1721 - acc: 0.0220
Epoch 5/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1716 - acc: 0.0225
Epoch 6/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1711 - acc: 0.0235
Epoch 7/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1698 - acc: 0.0245
Epoch 8/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1690 - acc: 0.0251
Epoch 9/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1686 - acc: 0.0257
Epoch 10/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1679 - acc: 0.0261
Epoch 11/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1674 - acc: 0.0267
Epoch 12/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1667 - acc: 0.0277
Epoch 13/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1656 - acc: 0.0285
Epoch 14/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1653 - acc: 0.0288
Epoch 15/20
 - 1s - loss: 3.1653 - acc: 0.0291
```

I used Sklearn library to build the same structure with the same data, and it works perfectly, shown me an accuracy higher than 0.5:

```
model = Pipeline([
        ('classifier', MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(1000), activation='relu',
                                     max_iter=20, verbose=2, batch_size=700, random_state=0))
    ])
```

I'm totally sure that I used the same data for both models, and this is how I prepare it:

```
def load_data():
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    with open('_DATA_train.txt', 'rb') as fp:
        train = pickle.load(fp)
    with open('_DATA_test.txt', 'rb') as fp:
        test = pickle.load(fp)

    x_train = train[:,0:(train.shape[1]-1)]
    y_train = train[:,(train.shape[1]-1)]
    y_train = le.fit_transform(y_train).reshape([-1,1])

    x_test = test[:,0:(test.shape[1]-1)]
    y_test = test[:,(test.shape[1]-1)]
    y_test = le.fit_transform(y_test).reshape([-1,1])

    print(x_train.shape, '  ' , y_train.shape)
    print(x_test.shape, '  ' , y_test.shape)
    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test
```

What is the problem with the Keras structure?

Edited:

it's a multi-class classification problem: y_training [0 ,1, 2, 3]

Comment: Some questions:
- Are you sure 601 features are required? Have you checked for correlations?
- Consider reducing the number of neurons and add an hidden layer.
- What is the rate of you data? I mean, the positive/total.

Comment: what is your optimizers and learnig rate? Have you tried lowering your learning rate?

Comment: It seems to me that you are not shuffling the dataset before training, and you may therefore be witnessing overfitting on the class with less variance.

Comment: I would try another loss function, the binary cross_entropy is supposed to work with 2 labels, if I understand well here you are expecting one real value as output, maybe you should try a mean_squared_error.

Comment: On a binary classification problem like you have, if the training accuracy is below 0.5 then something is probably wrong. Can you post an example of what your labels look like because I suspect that is the problem. Your labels should all be either a 0 or a 1 with the way your network is set up.

Comment: @Marco , I changed the loss function, I forgot that it's not a binary classification problem .. but also the results are fixed in somehow .. they are increasing but in very slow and tiny amount

Comment: @Minion if your results are increreasing to slow you should try to increase your learning rate, and I suggest also to add a Dropout step like in this case. https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-regularization-deep-learning-models-keras/

Comment: @Jeremy , it works now, thanx .. I built the network based on an example from a binary problem which confused me ..

Comment: @Minion you can answer your own question; in the future, if your answer is thorough and well documented others can benefit by referring to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a multiclass problem your labels should be one hot encoded. For example if the options are [0 ,1, 2, 3] and the label is 1 then it should be [0, 1, 0, 0].

Your final layer should be a dense layer with 4 units and an activation of softmax.

```
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

And your loss should be categorical_crossentropy

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='RMSprop')
```